# How can I scroll from keyboard in Konsole?

Tags: kde, konsole

Is it possible to either create a custom shortcut, or use an existing one, to scroll with a keyboard command in [Konsole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konsole)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to superuser. Do any of these help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255070/how-do-you-scroll-up-down-on-the-linux-console, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60382/how-to-scroll-in-a-terminal-using-keyboard, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405738/scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-in-konsole?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15255305/391753
Shift + PgUp or Shift + PgDown should work. I just confirmed that it indeed works in Konsole